# @ifpackageloaded syntax

Tags: hyperref, conditionals

I have the following call to the `\hypersetup` macro:

```
\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={My Name},
    pdftitle={Title},
    pdfkeywords={LaTeX, PDF},
    pdfcreator={PDFLaTeX},
    pdfproducer={PDFLaTeX},
}
```

Which is only usable if I have the `hyperref` package loaded. So I tried to wrap it under conditionals:

```
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}
{\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={My Name},
    pdftitle={Title},
    pdfkeywords={LaTeX, PDF},
    pdfcreator={PDFLaTeX},
    pdfproducer={PDFLaTeX},
}}
{ }
```

and I get the following compilation error:

```
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
\@->\spacefactor 
                 \@m {}
l.19 \@
```

Comment: `\makeatletter\@ifpackageloaded{packagename}{true}{false}\makeatother` -- You need this syntax only in a document, in a `.sty` or `.cls` file it's not necessary!

Comment: You need to wrap the conditional between a `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair. See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)